# Boost filesystem incompatible with c++11 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-filesystem

I've had a maddening problem that I need some help with.  I'm attempting to write a file finder or parser that finds all of the files of a given format in a directory.  I want this to be a class, and I also want it to run in it's own separate thread from main().  I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS, with it's boost installation (1.54).  Here is the vanilla version of my code, just linking against boost::system.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class fileFinder {
    private:
        std::string dName;

    public:
        fileFinder() : dName("") { };
        fileFinder(const std::string &dirName) : dName(dirName) { };
        void runFileFinder(void) { 
            std::string fileFinderName = "Hi from filefinder!";
            std::cout << fileFinderName << std::endl;
        };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //Get the dirname, not safe yet
    std::string dirName = argv[1];

    fileFinder fFinderThread(dirName);
    std::thread t1(&fileFinder::runFileFinder, &fFinderThread);
    t1.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile, everything works out great, and the class gets instantiated, and then run in a separate thread.  I will link against boost_system just to show that everything is still ok.

```
> g++ -g -Wall -I/usr/include/boost/ -c rFileFinder.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
> g++ -g -Wall rFileFinder.o -o rFileFinder -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_system -std=c++11 -pthread
> ./rFileFinder abcd
Hi from filefinder: abcd
```

Now, since I want to find all the files of a certain type, using boost::filesystem would be awesome.  Even attempting to link against the boost::filesystem library produces a runtime threading error (just add -lboost_filesystem to the libraries).

```
> g++ -g -Wall -I/usr/include/boost/ -c rFileFinder.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
> g++ -g -Wall rFileFinder.o -o rFileFinder -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -std=c++11 -pthread
> ./rFileFinder abcd
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
 what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread.  Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And so, this is driving me insane, since I am going to need to have both multithreading capabilities (there is a lot more than just this part of the problem).  I've attempted to tease this answer out of the internet, but basically everything I come across is about how the linking to c++11 or pthread isn't done correctly in the compilation and linker steps.  Is there a way for me to use both std::thread and boost::filesystem, or am I just hosed?

Comment: I don't think it will solve anything, but you can drop the pthread if you use c++11. What gcc version are you using?

Comment: At least some versions of Ubuntu have separate multithreaded versions of boost libraries. Try installing all available boost packages and look for `*-mt.so` libraries.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu.  As well, there weren't any *-mt libraries, but I thought that the boost libraries normally were multithreaded, even though on my mac they all carry the -mt affix.  I am able to drop the pthread and suddenly everything works.

Comment: On my system (not Ubuntu) there are separate boost...-mt.so libraries. You may have missed some boost packages. boost is also known to misbehave in programs compiled with `-std=c++11` if it itself compiled without.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to the posix threads library on your system

With gcc or clang, typically this is done by supplying `g++ -pthread` on the command line.

Technically you should specify to link with the respective dynamic library too

```
g++ -pthread test.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem
```

Comment: It turns out that if I simply omit the -pthread option from my code, it works.  There is a conflict between using boost threads and c++11 threads in the boost::filesystem library for some reason.  I am getting it to compile correctly on my mac.  Now if only I could get it to actually recognize a directory, which it's not at the moment, but compiling is at least a start.

Answer (score 0):

Using g++ 4.8, it seems that one cannot have both the -pthread and -std=c++11 flags for the compiler options.  They mutually exclude each other on mac (with homebrew gcc48) and on my Ubuntu distro (14.04LTS with g++-4.8).  Just use -std=c++11.